# Participant / Subject Pool Management Solutions

Tags: methodology, software, teaching-of-psychology

I am searching for a subject pool management system for human subject research. Almost all institutions appear to use Sona-systems. Do any alternatives exist?

Comment: experimetrix is another popular one

Answer (score 2):

here is an open source project: http://www.goeritz.net/panelware/

With a paper: http://www.goeritz.net/panelware/BRM4.pdf

Might be a little outdated but still work ...